# How to recyle the linked list node immediately after delete it in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I want to delete a node in linked list and recyle it immediately in Python, but I don't know how to achieve that, here is example code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

# delete node
def delete_node_after(pre_node):
    deleted_node = pre_node.next
    pre_node.next = pre_node.next.next
    del deleted_node        # incorrect, it is only delete `deleted_node` reference to l2

def test():
    l1 = ListNode(1)
    l2 = ListNode(2)
    l3 = ListNode(3)

    l1.next = l2
    l2.next = l3

    delete_node_after(l2)

    print(l1.next.val)
    print(l2.val)           # l2 is still here
```

The reason I want to do this is that this Linked List will have a long lifecyle, and I want release deleted node's memory immediately.

Or I only can wait for Python to auto recycle it by Reference Count after some while?

Comment: Python objects will be garbage collected if there are no references to them anymore. `del` removes one reference only, not the object. You could set other referencing names to `None`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75344/how-to-completely-delete-an-object-through-python

Comment: yeah, I know `del` is not the answer, so I want to ask @KlausD.

Comment: @Recessive That solution applies only to the blender library used there.

Comment: usually you make sure the only reference to that node is the element before's `.next`